# Invalid token error when using jsonb_insert in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

As a little bit of background. I want to fill a column with jsonb values using values from other columns. Initially, I used this query:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET column_name = 
 row_to_json(rowset)
 FROM (SELECT column1, column2 FROM myTable)rowset
```

However, this query seems to run for way too long (a few hours before I stopped it) on a dataset with 9 million records. So I looking for a solution with the second FROM clause and found the jsonb_insert function. To test the query I first ran this sample query:

```
SELECT jsonb_insert('{}','{column1}','500000')
```

Which gives `{'column1':500000}` as output. Perfect, so I tried to fill the value using the actual column:

```
SELECT jsonb_insert('{}':,'{column1}',column1) FROM myTable WHERE id = <test_id>
```

This gives a syntax error and a suggestion to add argument types, which leads me to the following:

```
SELECT jsonb_insert('{}':,'{column1}','column1') 
FROM myTable WHERE id = <test_id>

SELECT jsonb_insert('{}'::jsonb,'{column1}'::jsonb,column1::numeric(8,0)) 
FROM myTable WHERE id = <test_id>
```

Both these queries give invalid input type syntax error, with Token 'column1' is invalid.

I really can not seem to find the correct syntax for these queries using documentation. Does anyone know what the correct syntax would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `jsonb_insert` function might need to use `jsonb` type for the `new_value` parameter

> jsonb_insert(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb [, insert_after boolean])

if we want to get number type of JSON, we can try to cast the column as string type before cast `jsonb`

if we want to get a string type of JSON, we can try to use `concat` function with double-quotes sign.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (column1 varchar(50),column2 int);

INSERT INTO myTable  VALUES('column1',50000);

SELECT jsonb_insert('{}','{column1}',concat('"',column1,'"')::jsonb) as JsonStringType,
       jsonb_insert('{}','{column2}',coalesce(column2::TEXT,'null')::jsonb) as JsonNumberType
FROM myTable
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=56f579512c57aca3a6deeffd8258f905)

**Note**

if our column value might be null we can try to put `'null'` for `coalesce` function as `coalesce(column2::TEXT,'null')`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. I'll give it a shot on my dataset.

Comment: Would you perhaps also know how to deal with NULL values in for example the column with number values?

Comment: @JeroenVermunt I had edited my asnwer you can try that